# Is PostDoc fellowship considered a job or a degree?

Tags: postdocs

I am wondering if a Postdoctoral fellowship is considered a job or a degree

1. in the academia
2. to the private-sector employer
3. by the Visa-issuer country

?

Comment: I think this should be closed as 'depending on individual factors'; while I agree in general with Buffy's answer, how an academic institutional, employer, or visa-issuer treats any given position is **entirely up to them**. They need not be consistent with each other within or between categories. You can't rely on a general answer, you need to check the specific circumstances that apply/may apply to **you**.

Comment: Only the visa issuing authorities could give you an authoritative answer as to what they consider any position and what conditions they would attach to a visa.  I agree with @BryanKrause on this being too dependent on precise details to answer.

Comment: Agreed that the visa situation should be clarified with the country of interest and not internet strangers - as a data point, I know that postdoc fellowships are legally treated as studentships by Israeli immigration, presumably because it greatly simplifies the visa arrangements (unless, presumably, the Law of Return applies).

Comment: There's a small college here in Austin that has no graduate program, but calls its adjunct positions "Post Doc".  I think it's dishonest, but they didn't ask me how to run their school.  They're clearly trying to sugar-coat the fact that the position is not tenure-track.

Comment: FWIW. Back in the day  (1990) a one semester post doctoral grant was covered under my student visa (F1) to US as "practical training". The training had to take place within 12 months of graduation. Actually it was 6 months + 6 months. As I has graduated in May I had to get the extension sorted out with the INS in November. Normally a post-doc position has a longer term, and won't fit into a student visa period, so expect more paperwork. You absolutely need to find out about the rules.

Comment: The "practical training" moniker is mostly a scam used against researchers to deny them their proper status as employees (claiming that after, what, 10 years of "training" they still need more "training" to be considered researcher... please).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add an answer, since there are some nuances to the question revolving around what the OP meant by a 'PostDoc fellowship', particularly the 'fellowship' bit.

At my US national lab, a postdoc is a particular job category - a limited-term position with a requirement of having obtained one's PhD less than 6 years prior to application. But, it is a job - the lab pays a salary, takes out appropriate taxes (Medicare, social security, withholdings per a W-4) and offers benefits (medical, vacation, ...). Even our special postdoctoral 'fellowships' are a job, just with more funding available with them. To my experience at classic tech companies (Bell Labs, IBM Research), this same thing holds. The postdoc is a job with salary, benefits, and a W-2 at the end of the year.

Many university postdocs are similar - they are an employee of the university, paid a salary, have taxes withheld, etc. etc.

HOWEVER - postdoc Fellowships may well be different. As one example, [Harvard's School of Public Health](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/faculty-affairs/postdoctoral-research-fellows/postdoc-benefits/postdoctoral-fellows-stipendee-taxes/) notes (my bolding):

> Postdoctoral Fellows – Stipendee Taxes

> Research fellows paid with a stipend should be aware of the tax implications related to this form of payment. Since stipendee postdoctoral fellows **are not employees** of the University, income taxes will not be withheld from stipends. In addition, the University’s contribution to a stipendee postdoc’s benefit plans must be treated as taxable income to the postdoc (i.e. imputed income). The expectation is that postdocs who receive a stipend will make quarterly estimated federal and state tax payments.

Perusing the information for NSF Postdocs would indicate something similar - the NSF sends $$$ directly to the postdoc, while any teaching salary is paid by the institution they are at. So the teaching may be a job, but the postdoctoral fellowship is not (but income taxes need to be paid).

So, while a postdoc is not a degree (but requires one!), it also may not be a "job".

Comment: These nuances you describe are real and worth noting, but legalities aside, it’s completely accurate to say a postdoc is a job. It has reasonably well-defined duties, you work in a place that is a pretty standard workplace, you report to a mentor/supervisor, and you get paid every month. So, saying it’s not necessarily a job seems pretty misleading to me.

Comment: That you are not an employee _of Harvard_ and that it is not a job are different propositions.

Comment: @DanRomik The "get paid every month" (or twice a month in some places) isn't always true. Some recipients of external fellowships/stipends have told me they get paid a lump sum once per year, and have to deal with all taxes and insurance on their own. In such cases, the postdoc is perhaps more akin to an independent contractor of the stipend-awarding organization than an employee of a university.

Answer (score 11):

A post doc is just a job. It is a way for a recent doctoral recipient to extend their research so as to become more employable in general, usually in seeking an academic position.

There is nothing like a degree "awarded" for a postdoc. An office and a paycheck and access to other researchers, but little else.

A nation might issue an employment (not student) visa to permit the person to take the job, but it isn't a degree seeking position like a PhD candidate can claim.

Companies probably care very little unless the research is of interest to the company.

Academia cares only in so much as it keeps viable candidates "in the game" for a while if they can't be hired at the moment and/or are judged to need a bit more "seasoning".

But, not a degree or anything similar. A job.

Comment: I agree it's primarily just a job, but it's worth noting that in some places there is a distinction made between a regular employee and an "employee-in-training" for legal and benefits purposes.

Comment: @BryanKrause, hmmm. I think "employee in training" equates to employee. It isn't like an unpaid internship. Nearly everywhere has various classes of employee. Why do you think that qualification is important? I also think that early career academics get abused (a lot). Adjuncts are much worse, but the prevalence of postdocs today is IMO a failure of the system. There  is a great imbalance that we haven't collectively figured out how to fix, leaving such folks at risk.

Comment: "How we want it to work" and "how it actually works" may not be the same thing; I agree that a post doc is certainly not a *degree*, but also "a job" is not always just a job, in ways that can have important implications for some of the situations OP mentions, like visa/immigration.

Comment: I have never heard of a post-doc being given a student visa.

Comment: @HermanToothrot, but a temporary visa for a time-limited job would be common in lots of places.

Comment: @Buffy yes most definitely, but it cannot be compared to a student visa which often comes with working restrictions because the primary purpose is to study not to work.

Comment: @Buffy - a visa is not a (permanent) residence permit. As a (US) postdoc in Amsterdam, I got my temporary residence/work permit renewed once a year.

Comment: Just to nitpick slightly: I think it's better to describe postdocs as "A junior and fixed-term faculty position similar to residency for physicians which serves as a necessary prerequisite to qualify for permanent faculty positions." More about labor supply/demand than any real shift in what "seasoned" means.

Comment: @HermanToothrot, I'm sorry if I implied otherwise, but my edit should make my intention clear. Not a student visa, an employment related visa. And not permanent AFAIK in those "most" places. Certainly not in US.